# Replace PHP Class Dependencies from Git Bash

Tags: php, bash

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and a RethinkDB service provider that uses a different dependency than normally migrated files, which is all handled for you if you write your migrations manually, but we build up our migrations using http://www.laravelsd.com/.  During initial development tweaks occur so I wanted to write a quick bash script to run through /data/migrations/*.php files and replace the dependency if newly export migrations are dropped in.  So far I've tried a bunch of different solutions with no luck and tried augmenting them too.

This seemed like it should work to replace `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` with `duxet\Rethinkdb\Schema\Blueprint`:

```
cd database/migrations

grep --include={*.php} -rnl './' -e "Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint" | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint/duxet\Rethinkdb\Schema\Blueprint/g' @
```

Any suggestions why this isn't working?  I don't see anything else in --help that would be useful.